# Convert Mat to MemoryStream OpenCV for Android

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.android

With OpenCVSharp, it is very easy to convert a Mat object to MemoryStream.

```
private Stream GetStream(Mat mat, string ext)
{
    return mat.Clone().ToMemoryStream(ext);
}
```

How can I do this with Xamarin.OpenCV.Droid?

https://github.com/NAXAM/opencv-android-binding/

Comment: Are you trying to get the stream in png/jpg/... file format or just a clone of a Mat into a Stream?

Comment: I'd like to get the stream based on the file extension png, jpg, ...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Imgcodecs.Imencode` to populate a `MatOfByte` instance from a `Mat` instance and a desired encoding and then you can acquire a `byte[]` from that to populate a `Stream`.

Note: OpenCVSharp has a series of helper functions that perform those functions when calling their `ToMemoryStream` method.

#### Example (read a png from a file and save it to a jpg):

```
using (var matFromPng = Imgcodecs.Imread(cachedFileName, Imgcodecs.ImreadColor))
using (var vect = new MatOfByte())
{
    if (Imgcodecs.Imencode(".jpg", matFromPng, vect))
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(vect.ToArray());
        // Do something with your stream...

        cachedFileName = Path.Combine(CacheDir.AbsolutePath, "her.jpg");
        using (var cacheFilestreamToJpeg = new FileStream(cachedFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(cacheFilestreamToJpeg);
        }
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In some cases, I'd like to use the memory stream (a local variable `stream` in your code) as the return value of the method, which will be sent to a DB for image analysis. Can I directly return `stream` in this case?

Comment: @user4134476 Returning a Stream is fine, just dispose of it as soon as you can...

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll never fail to dispose of a stream.